# Supermicro X7DBE Motherboard Built into Desktop Case - Boot Problems, No OS Can't Install

Tags: supermicro

So that's where I'm at, I bought a Supermicro motherboard and installed into a Desktop case with lots of fans and brand new supermicro heatsinks with fans because I was initially having some overheating issues which seem to be gone now and not the problem. I just replaced the CMOS batter and have been toying with settings this is the best I can do if there's anymore information I can provide to help get me going I will supply no problem. Oh ya there were some disk issues so I ordered a new hard drive because the 2 old ones weren't even being recognized by parted magic, I managed to get one cleaned but that didn't solve the issue so now I have one plugged in trying to solve the issue of the computer not working. The only Desktop UI or Terminal I've ever sucessfully got to on this machine was parted magic or DSL Linux loaded purely from RAM and that's it.

This is what happens when I try and load my installer of proxmox from a USB...I get to the grub menu and then it begins to boot up after pressing install PVE, and freezes exactly at this point.

```
mounting proc filesystem
mounting sys filesystem
commandline: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/linux26 ro ramdisk_size=16777216 rw quiet splash=silent nomodeset
loading drivers: intel_rng pata_acpi mac_hid uhci_hcd i2c_i801 ehci_pci serio_raw psmouse pcspkr kvm_intel intel_powerclamp
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert `intel_rng`: No such device
searching for block device containing the ISO proxmox-ve-6.3-1
with ISO ID `5bf99256-2f32-11eb-86f2-b7e9f6c90679`
testing again in 5 seconds
[    7.9286221] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No caching mode page found
[    7.9298021] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
testing device `/dev/sdb` for ISO
found Proxmox VE ISO
Starting Proxmox installation
Installing additional hardware drivers
[ ok ] Starting hotplug events dispatcher: systemd-udevd.
[ ok ] Synthesizing the initial hotplug events (subsytems)...done.
[ ok ] Synthesizing the initial hotplug events (devices)...done.

[....] Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...
```

Logs at the start of boot:

```
Phoenix Trusted Core(tm) Server
Copyright 1985-2005 Phoenix Tech

Supermicro X7DB8/X7DB8+/X7DB8+ Phoenix BIOS
Intel Xeon CPU
CPU = 2 Processors Detected
RAM Type DDR2-667 FSB at 1333 MHz
System RAM Passed
System BIOS Shadowed
Video BIOS Shadowed
Fixed DIsk 0: 500Gb
System Config Data updated
ERROR
System Config Data Read Error
```

After replacing the CMOS battery now I can't even boot to the BIOS I'm getting all but a black screen and can't give any keyboard commands or see anything (nor hear any beeps) just black screen and fans running.

It will start working and then stops but can never actually sucessfully boot the system. Starting to feel like this is hopeless.

cheers Thanks for reading even if you don't have any advice.

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay, no problem should I remove it? I can try super user, I was getting a lot of useful information surrounding similar issues and I posted here but will take it to Super User. Thanks